# Defining custom color scale using hex codes with choroplethr

Tags: choroplethr

I've created a custom color palette for a project that I'd like to apply to several county-level choropleths (desired hex codes: #FFB025, #FF7913, #D72D5C, #B76BA3, #5F4B8B). I've been able to create the choropleths in `choroplethr` without difficulty using the code below:

```
install.packages(“choroplethr")
install.packages(“choroplethrMaps")
library(choroplethr)

county_choropleth(df_tx_example,
legend     =    "Index Score",
num_colors =    5,
state_zoom =    c(“texas”))
```

All tutorials I've been able to find only demonstrate how to apply different `brewer` scales to choropleths, but I'd like to get more specific if possible. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

A `choroplethr` generated object is a `ggplot` object. You can apply the similar `ggplot` graphical grammar on top of your `choroplethr` generated object.

Below is a quick add-on to your existing example. I've got this hint while reading Ari's older blog post ([here](https://arilamstein.com/blog/2016/02/01/mapping-religious-adherence-r-now-demographics/)).

*Note:* you need to change your `num_colors` to `0` (or `1`) as it represents a continuous color scale.

```
# sample data
data(df_pop_county)
g <- NULL

# your example
g <- county_choropleth(df_pop_county,
                       legend     = "Index Score",
                       num_colors = 1,
                       state_zoom = "texas")

# using the `viridis` color scale
library(viridis)
g <- g + scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Viridis scale", colours = viridis(32))
g
```

### Default color scale

[image]

### Custom color scale

[image]